# Multer is not identifying the multipart/form-data request file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

**Client (ReactJS/Axios):**

```
const handleSubmit = async (croppedImage: any) => {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', croppedImage);
    formData.append('name', croppedImage.name)

    api.post(
        '/firebase',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        }
    )
        .then(() => console.log('Success'))
        .catch(e => console.error(e))
}
```

**Multer middleware:**

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const multer = require('multer');

const error = new Error('Only .png format allowed!');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (!file) return cb(error);
        cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (!file) return cb(error);
        const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
        cb(null, uuidv4(4) + '-' + fileName)
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (!file) return cb(error);
        if (file.mimetype == "image/png") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            return cb(error);
        }
    }
});

module.exports = upload.single('file');
```

**Next():**

async (req, res) => {

```
const fileName = req.file.filename;
```

> Here req.file is
> undefined!

```
...
```

}

[image]

When I try to pass a image using Axios, *req.file* appears as *undefined* in the controller.

I think the error is when passing the multipart/form-data, because when I do it through *Insonmia Rest* it works!

Comment: show the controller code, where you use multer

Answer (score 0):

**Form** Example :

```html
<form action="/insert" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" class="btn btn-default">            
    </div>
</form>
```

**Save and get file**

```js
if (req.files) 
{
   let uploaded_file = req.files[0].filename;
   console.log(uploaded_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

croppedImage was like a blob url or something like that, so:

**Client (ReactJS/Axios):**

```
let blob = await fetch(croppedImage).then(r => r.blob());
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, 'file.jpeg')
```